# I want to send a file in binary data from my webpage using JQuery

Tags: jquery, file, post, upload

I want to send a file to the server in binary, not using the normal form post method because that method encoding is not binary. The reason is that I have a IPad application which sends a binary file to the server and I need to do the same in JQuery in a web browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: But that encoding is enctype: 'multipart/form-data' which is not binary, its something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use base64 encoding? Try this: http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode:358